# UITableviewcell make some controls nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am using `Custom` `tableViewCell`. Cell contains some `labels` etc but out of all rows two rows contain graph.

The thing is that I have kept graph(sub class of view) hidden, but don't want to load graph for each cell. If I do that graph `nil`, then it goes from that 2 rows also.

Please suggest me way so that `table` does not consume large memory because of that graph.

The code is something like this

```
    self.btnTitleOfSection = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    self.btnTitleOfSection.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 316, 30);
    [self.btnTitleOfSection setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.btnTitleOfSection setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [self.btnTitleOfSection setContentHorizontalAlignment:UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.btnTitleOfSection];

    self.viewGraph1 = [[Graph1 alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 5, 240, 140)];
    self.viewGraph1.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.viewGraph1];

    self.viewGraph2 = [[Graph2 alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 5, 240, 110)];
    self.viewGraph2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.viewGraph2];

    self.lblGraphH = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 145, 103, 21)];
    self.lblGraphH.text = @"Week";
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.lblGraphH];
```

I don't want to load viewGraph1 and viewGraph2 every time.

Will I have to use two cells only or I can use 1 cell and solve the issue of memory.

Comment: Please Post code u have tried.

Comment: Have 2 prototype cells, one with a graph one without

Comment: Please Provide `CellforRowAtIndex` code.

Comment: I have posted the code the way I create custom cell. In CellforRowAtIndex in other rows I keep the viewGraph1 and viewGraph2 hidden

Answer (score 0):

Your graph will be shown on other cell simply because your cell is being reused. You have to implement a default value for your graph in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and only enable your graph under certain condition as follows:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(!cell)
    {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }

   [cell.graph setHidden:YES];

   // check for your condition here
   if(indexPath.row == yourIndex)
   {
     // show the graph only in this cell
     [cell.graph setHidden:NO];
   }
}
```

Comment: the doubt I have with this is, will other cells also use memory for graph. I don't want that as graph will load more memory

Comment: Well I have no idea how you are generating this graph. Instead of `[cell.graph setHidden:NO]` you can implement your logic. This was just an example of how and were you should put your code. This code will ignore all cells with `indexPath` different than the one you want. If this is what you're asking then yes no extra memory will be used on cell you don't want to display you graph on